# openrowset save to multiple rows

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have a xml file

```
<Out>
    <R>
        <S>
            <UID>111-20090817192401</UID>
        </S>
    </R>
</out>
<Out>
    <R>
        <S>
            <UID>222-30090817192401</UID>
        </S>
    </R>
</Out>
```

I want to save each of  node into a SQL server row. How can I do that?

```
SELECT @XMLDATA=BulkColumn 
 FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\test.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) AS xmlData
```

This returns both the XML outernodes as one record. How can I do this?

**Expected output**

```
create table dbo.temp(ID  INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Out varchar(10) null,R varchar(10) null,S varchar(10) null,uid varchar(20) null);
insert into dbo.temp values(null,null,null,111-20090817192401)
insert into dbo.temp values(null,null,null,222-30090817192401)
```

Answer (score 1):

After you read the file contents, cast it to xml and use `nodes()` to query it like so:

```
DECLARE @XMLDATA AS xml 
SELECT @XMLDATA=CAST(BulkColumn AS xml)
 FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\test.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) AS xmlData

create table dbo.temp(ID  INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Out varchar(10) null,R varchar(10) null,S varchar(10) null,uid varchar(20) null);

INSERT INTO dbo.temp(uid)
SELECT r.value('.', 'varchar(20)')
FROM @XMLDATA.nodes('//UID') x(r)
```